# Cannot ssh into my vps ipv6 ip : Network is unreachable

Tags: centos, ssh, vps, ipv6, putty

The dashboard of my hosting company regxa provides me with a root password and **ipv6** address to my **CentOS** server, no ipv4

I have tried using both *putty* and *ssh* cmd in my linux machine to connect to the ipv6 address, but the response is always the same **Network is unreachable**

Lets use a reserved range as example - `2001:db8::1` - to demonstrate the following commands I have tried.

```
ssh root@2001:db8::1
ssh root@[2001:db8::1]
ssh -6 root@2001:db8::1
ssh -6 root@[2001:db8::1]

ssh -6 2001:db8::1
ssh -6 [2001:db8::1]

All cmds return Network is unreachable
```

I've tried the same in putty, without the ssh prefix, and the response is the same

**ping** and **traceroute**

```
traceroute -6 2001:db8::1

returns Network is unreachable


ping -6 2001:db8::1

returns ping: connect: Network is unreachable
```

I've tried opening a ticket with myvps host regxa to ask about connecting with ssh, after a day of waiting they closed the ticket, dont recommend going with them again

**Trouble Shooting**

Trying to ping googles ipv6 - 2a00:1450:4001:806::200e - from my linux machine also returns **Network is unreachable**

```
ip addr show

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s20u1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:1e:10:1f:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.9.100/24 brd 192.168.9.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp0s20u1
       valid_lft 78826sec preferred_lft 78826sec
    inet6 fe80::77d2:3243:db4e:dbb6/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Does appear that I have an ipv6 address

ipv4 has **scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp0s20u1**

ipv6 has **scope link noprefixroute valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever**

What if I switched these configs over?

Comment: Please edit your question to add useful troubleshooting information. Do not use placeholder IP address use real ones, which network matters for routing over the internet. (If you must obfuscate don't make up random hex numbers, use something reserved like the docs prefix)   Show the IP address and routing table of your machine and this server, such as on Linux `ip -6 a; ip -6 r;`   Show you have functional IPv6 such as with https://test-ipv6.com/   results.

Comment: @JohnMahowald added results of `ip addr show`
also replaced placeholder ipv6 with a real ipv6

Comment: Do *not* use random IPv6 addresses as examples. It generates confusion. Use your own, or use `2001:db8::/32` which is set aside for documentation use.

Answer (score 2):

> Trying to ping googles ipv6 - 2a00:1450:4001:806::200e - from my linux machine also returns Network is unreachable

You don't have functioning IPv6. If your ISP is not able to give you this you may look into a tunnel from e.g. HE.net

> fe80::77d2:3243:db4e:dbb6/64

This is a link local address. They will only ever work locally in your network, and not on the Internet.

Comment: To summarize: this means the problem is not on the server, it's on the client.

Comment: Is there a possiblity that I can enable/disable this from a config file on my machine, or is it 100% ISP based

Comment: I have no idea. We don't know anything about your ISP or your configuration.

Comment: @vidarlo some of my configuration is posted above. hence why I am here trying to resolve the problem

Comment: Talk with your ISP. We can't know what they support and not. And generally the relevant config is your router; all modern OS will work fine with IPv6 if the network supports it.